# How to successfully write an MVC Route definition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

Can someone please help me find what's wrong AND still explain to me how a controller knows which route definition it should use (since in lots of situations, a URI can fit more than just one route definition)?

Here's my problem...

Controller Method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult PreencherFormulario(int idPacientePesquisa, int idFormularioPesquisa)
```

Routes (all that are defined on Global.asax):

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
        "Busca",
        "{controller}/{action}/{SearchString}/{SearchSubString}/{id}"
    );
    RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
        "Participacao",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}"
    );
    RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
        "ParticipacaoPesquisa",
        "{controller}/{action}/{idPesquisa}/{nrProntuario}",
        null,
        new { idPesquisa = @"\d+" }
     );

    //!!! This should be the one used...
    RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
        name: "PreencherForm",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{idPacientePesquisa}/{idFormularioPesquisa}",
        defaults: new { idPacientePesquisa = 1, idFormularioPesquisa = 1 },
        constraints: new { idPacientePesquisa = @"\d+", idFormularioPesquisa = @"\d+" }
     );

    RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
        "AdicionarRegraCID",
        "{controller}/{action}/{a}/{b}/{c}",
        new { controller = "Pesquisas", action = "AdicionarRegraCID", MetodoResultado = "", MetodoCancelar = "" }
    );
```

The URL:

```
http://localhost:61404/RealizacaoPesquisa/PreencherFormulario/1/1
```

The error:

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'idPacientePesquisa' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult PreencherFormulario(Int32, Int32)' in 'Prometheus.Controllers.RealizacaoPesquisaController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Nome do parâmetro: parameters
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with the following route which has null for default and since that route comes before the route you suspect and the routeurl is of the same format as that of the next one. This route gets considered and it fails while routing because your action arguments are non nullable int.

```
  RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
        "ParticipacaoPesquisa",
        "{controller}/{action}/{idPesquisa}/{nrProntuario}",
        null, /*<--- This is the culprit*/
        new { idPesquisa = @"\d+" }
  );
```

Remember that order of the routes matter and you should keep the default route on the bottom as well. Move the above the route below the route that is in question. You need to rearrange your routes. Here is what happened:

You hit the url : `http://localhost:61404/RealizacaoPesquisa/PreencherFormulario/1/1`

It looks in to the routing table and find the first match and that is

```
"{controller}/{action}/{idPesquisa}/{nrProntuario}",
```

So it then tries to call your action with the argument `idPesquisa` which is what is mapped in this route.

But your action expects something else as the parameter names and they are non nullable as well, hence if fails.

Comment: Ok, I see that now... But even if I describe some defaults, I can't understand how this would help - since both URLs are complete (with all parts present), the default would not matter, right?

Comment: @MarceloMyara Problem is the ordering of routes. Since that route pattern also matches your url pattern and it comes before the intended route it takes the first one. That is why it is also advised to move the default route to the bottom. Try always putting more generic routes on bottom and specific ones above them.

Answer (score 1):

First you want to write your routes from more specific to more general. It uses the first one it matches.

So your problem is that your route matches this route and you are setting the idPacientPesqusa to null.

```
 RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
        "ParticipacaoPesquisa",
        "{controller}/{action}/{idPesquisa}/{nrProntuario}",
        null, <-- here!!
        new { idPesquisa = @"\d+" }
     );
```

It appears that you are trying to have a route per controller/action so you could do something like this

```
 RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
        name: "PreencherForm",
        url:"RealizacaoPesquisa/PreencherFormulario/{idPacientePesquisa}/{idFormularioPesquisa}",
        defaults: new { controller = "RealizacaoPesquisa", action = "PreencherFormulario", idPacientePesquisa = 1, idFormularioPesquisa = 1 },
        constraints: new { idPacientePesquisa = @"\d+", idFormularioPesquisa = @"\d+" }
     );
```

Comment: Jared, yes, i thought of something like that. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I just figure out that to put this to work I had to specify a default value for "controller" and "action", otherwise I would receive an error saying that the action or controller word were missing from the URL pattern.

Comment: @MarceloMyara ah yes. Pardon my copy and paste error. I've updated my answer.